# With specified numbers from an ArrayList,how do I make the checkbox in my listview visible?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have an `ArrayList` of phone numbers:

```
ArrayList<String> MatchingContacts;
```

In my `phone_inflate_listview.xml` I have checkbox visibilty set to `invisible`:

```
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:clickable="true"
 />
```

If `phoneNumberofContact` belongs to `MatchingContacts`, I want this phone number (can be one or many) to appear at the top of the `ListView`, and the other phone numbers to appear underneath.

I do this with this code, in my `AsyncTask doInBackground`:

```
   //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts*/
            if (MatchingContacts.contains(phoneNumberofContact))

            {
                // insert the contact at the beginning of the listview
                selectPhoneContacts.add(0, selectContact);
            }

            else {
                // insert it at the end (default)
                selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
            }

            selectContact.setName(phoneNameofContact);
            selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumberofContact);
        }
```

How can I make the `checkbox` appear visible, for the numbers at the top of the `ListView`, the ones that belong to `MatchingContacts`?

Instead of just `selectPhoneContacts.add(0, selectContact);` I tried:

```
        selectPhoneContacts.add(0, selectContact);
        checkBoxforContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but I got an error, saying I had to do this in the UI thread. So in my `onPostExecute` I added:

```
    //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts*/
    if (MatchingContacts.contains(phoneNumberofContact))

    {
        checkBoxforContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

No errors, the app loads fine, but all my checkboxes are still not visible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

selectContact - can have one more variable say "isCbVisible" indicating whether checkbox is enabled/disable. Then, you set value of "isCbVisible" to true whenever conditions is satisfied inside doInBackground.
In getView() of listview method, you need to check value of "isCbVisible" and then show/hide checkbox.